# how to create a circular imageButton in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Guys i have created a imageButton in my layout file and set a circular png image as its background.but when i am running my application, its displaying me a square button with my given image placed in the middle of it.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/sliderr" />
```

Comment: you can do this by code.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

add `android:background="@null"`

Comment: This solution is good and simple, but if you want to add Ripple Effect to your ImageButton, this might not be the best solution, as the ripple effect will still run through the whole square, not only the image.

Comment: android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:padding="10dp"
adding this will create round imagebutton with ripples

Comment: @ViniciusQueiroz you're right. The answer is older than ripples in Android SDK though :)

Answer (score 17):

Make a new shape XML in `res/drawable/round_button.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000" 
        android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Use this shape as the button's background:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:src="@drawable/sliderr" />
```

You may also want to add `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` to your button to make the image the same size as the button, and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` if your image has unequal height/width.

Answer (score 7):

try to add this xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#eeffffff" />
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"  
    android:topRightRadius="8dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dip"/>
</shape>
```